# Do I need to save the image at @1x, @2x, @3x?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cocoa-touch, retina

I have a section on an app of mine that shows all files created and saved by the user. To speed up things, when the user saves the project I save a thumbnail of the rendered project. That thumbnail will be loaded using

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile...]
```

My question is: this app is to run on iOS 7 and up devices. That includes all iPhone 4 and up (all retina) and all iPad (retina or not). So, we are dealing here with devices that in theory use @1x, @2x and @3x assets.

Do I need to save the thumbnail in all these resolutions? It sounds like this is not the way to do it.

any thoughts?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these images are created at runtime then they just need to cover the resolution of the current device *unless* you use iCloud to allow the data to be shared across all the user's devices; in that case you would need to support all resolutions.

Comment: What I mean is this: suppose I save just one thumbnail size at 3x but save it without @3x and later I load it using imageWithContentsOfFile and put that image on an imageView. Won't be produce the same results?

Comment: Yeah provided the correct scaling attributes have been set.